# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'IQueryable<int>'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting error in my "where" condition. Below is my code:

```
var elimentid = db.Consult.Where(x => x.EnquiryId == Patientid).Select(x => x.AilmentId);
var details = (from detail in db.M_SelfHelp
                join alimet in db.Aliment on detail.SubAilmentId equals alimet.AilmentId
                where (detail.AilmentId == elimentid)
                select new SelpHelp
                {
                    AlimemtName = alimet.Name,
                    Alimentid = alimet.AilmentId
                }
                ).ToList();
```

Please let me know whats wrong in my code ?

Comment: Slightly off topic, but why do you write **`Ailment`** in 4 different ways: `alimet`, `db.Aliment`, `alimet.AilmentId`, `elimentid`? Good programming starts with clear and proper naming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to materialize you first query to singular result :

```
var elimentid = db.Consult.Where(x => x.EnquiryId == Patientid)
                          .Select(x => x.AilmentId).FirstOrDefault();
```

or you can write:

```
var consult = db.Consult.Where(x => x.EnquiryId == Patientid).FirstOrDefault();
var elimentid = consult.AilmentId;
```

Right now it is not and `int`  but `IQueryable<int>` and you can't compare `int` with `IQueryable<int>` obviously using `==` operator.

Or you can also use `SingleOrDefault()` if we are sure that there will always be single record agianst the `EnquiryId` in `Consult`.

This would make your code compile and workable as well but might not give you expected results back from linq query, as if there are multiple rows expected from the first query and you want to put all rows against those ids, then you need to do some work.

Comment: Note that this fixes the compile error, but it also hides/ignores data if a Patient has more than 1 Consult record, resulting in a selected AilmentId that will be more or less random.